# Uk visit visa Host

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

Am yet to reapply for my UK visa after refusal,What are the required documents needed from a host in the UK who is not my sponsor but only providing accommodation for Uk visit visa ??

Answer (score 1):

The rules around a third party providing accommodation support https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf#page21 require that:

- there is a genuine personal or professional relationship between the third party and the applicant
- if the third party is in the UK, they must not be in breach of immigration law at the time of the decision on the visitor’s application.

No specific document to demonstrate the above is given in the ‘Supporting Documents’ guide https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk Typically, the requirements are fulfilled by the host providing the applicant with an invitation letter that explains why they are willing to have the applicant stay in their home, how long the applicant is going to stay, and that they have enough room for the visitor, for the entire period of the stated stay. The host should also provide evidence to prove their citizenship or immigration status in the UK.